# ios scrolling should begin at top of main view - not at tableview within the view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a coreplot graph and a tableview below it. When I scroll within the tableview, the tableview content scroll separately (with the top chart always visible). I want the scrolling to be associated with the main view. When the user scrolls, the chart should disappear and the tableview rows should start appearing (which is what a user would expect.) Please see below pic - would appreciate any help - thanks!
[image]

**SOLUTION**
As suggested in answer below set the chart view as a header of table viw

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:myChartView];
```

Then in your storyboard, drag the chart view within the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your chart view in the tableview's header view like this:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:myChartView];
```

Comment: Thanks - when I do that I get "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'" Do I need to change the storyboard (right now the chart view is above the table view in storyboard)

Comment: Yes, I think you should change the storyboard (I don't use storyboards, but in Interface Builder I would put the chart inside the table at the top; the tableHeaderView).